# How to assign values to IEnumerable<dynamic>

Tags: c#, razor, webmatrix

I have the following code:

```
var db = Database.Open("Text");
var headers = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Headers");

//headers is now an IEnumerable<dynamic>

string s = headers[0].Text; // Works correctly

headers[0].Text = "Some string";
```

If I try to assign "Some string" to the Text property of the headers I get the following error:

`Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord contains no definition for Text.`

How can I convert the headers object to a List/Array so that I am able to assign new values to it?

Comment: The value is read only., you can A) use s = "Some string" or B) try and use an update query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `DynamicRecord` class being returned from WebMatrix is effectively 'read-only'.  The DynamicObject does not allow setting of `Text`.

You would need to map this data onto your own classes if you want to make changes to the values, and not leave them within the original `dynamic` type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there a general way to map the `DynamicRecord` so I don't have to write a class for every table in the database?

Comment: You might want to look at Massive - https://github.com/robconery/massive - which is a light weight ORM which is a fancy way of saying give me some objects that i can manipulate and get and put into the database.